# RHEL 7 Repository Question

Tags: rhel, repository

I have a local RHEL 7 yum repository that's not connected to the Internet. I need to add some RPMs from CD to this repository manually. I can't seem to find any information on this after exhaustive searching. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Using `createrepo` against a directory will update its repo metadata or create it if none exists.

```
createrepo some/directory
```

Comment: You run this *after* copying the rpms into the repo directory, yes?

Comment: @docwebhead: Correct.

Answer (score 2):

The tool that's often used for this job is `createrepo`.

See f.ex. here for a howto: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sec-yum_repository